# How to execute the following formula in Ms excel 2013

Tags: excel, function

=IF(Y51-1<=0,0,Y51)

Had done a quick search for the same on the questions tab, which was unsuccessful. Incase this is a duplicate, a link to the original would be very helpful. 
Any firm of help will be appreciated. [image]

Comment: where is the comma ? ;)

Comment: When I type it out as a formula from the tab, it prints the cell in this way, without the commas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modification,

```
=Y51*((Y51-1)>0)
```

Your original problem may be a comma vs. semi-colon system list separator.

```
=IF(Y51-1<=0; 0; Y51)
```

Comment: That would be a much more confusing formula than the original. Instead of trying to not use the separators, the OP should learn once and for all what the separators are on their particular Excel installation. One cannot avoid separators forever.

Comment: I've inferred from the op's narrative and image that he/she typed the commas but they somehow didn't appear in the typed formula. Short of recommending that they buy a new k/b (or clean their old one) I can really only offer a non-separator solution.

Answer (score -1):

Your above formula of `=IF(Y51-1<=0,0,Y51)` is correct u just miss the two commas in the `IF` function. The syntax is `=IF(CONDITION,TRUE,FALSE)`